# Add new menu item in blackberry to launch my app

Tags: blackberry, java-me

In my application, I want to to add an item to the BlackBerry menu items and this item can launch my simple application.

how can I do that?

I am using blackberry JDE 7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the Blackberry sample **"MenuDemo"**  from Blackberry samples; Then you can understand;

To Import Blackberry Samples; Go to

> File-->Import-->Blackberry-->ImportBlackberrySamples-->DeselectAll-->and select the MenuDemo from samples; and click finish;(you can change the version at "Use a project Specific JRE");

Comment: i know im bad in English , thats why you all didn't get what i mean, thank you alishaik, guys its something about  ApplicationMenuItemRepository amir = ApplicationMenuItemRepository.getInstance(); and i'm trying to figure it out, thank you anyway

Comment: okay alishaik, now i know how to use and add **ApplicationMenuItemRepository** but it's in other java file, how can i call the java that contain my aplication , witch start with `public class myscreen1 extends Application {`

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is to extend UiApplication for your main class and make sure your development environment is compiling your application as a GUI app, then there will be an Icon placed on the home screen which will launch your app.

Comment: thank you Richard, i think you didn't understand me ^_^
i want to add a menu item to launch my app
i can see the icon, but i want a shortcut for the app in the menu content of the system

Comment: There are APIs for adding entries to system menus for the BlackBerry, but to use them you will be turning your simple application into a complex one that could have a deleterious effect on the OS.

Comment: thank you again, its for learning and missing around ^_^
is there a tutorial for that APIs .. and yeah i'm very new to blackberry and to java it self